# Solve numeric keypad puzzle using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, numbers, dom-events

I was attending an interview a few days ago and the company gave me an puzzle to solve using Javascript, but I could not complete it.

You can see the code here:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#phone").find("button").mouseup(function(event){
        var button_pressed = $(event.currentTarget).data("value")
        $("#result").val(t9($("#result").val(),button_pressed))
    })
})
function t9(text,button_pressed){
    // Write your code here
    return text
}
```

```css
#phone button{
    height: 50px;
    width: 75px;
}
#phone button span{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
#result{
    width: 225px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="phone">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="text" id="result" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button data-value="1" class="key">1
                <span>. , !</span>
            </button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button data-value="2" class="key">2
                <span>a b c</span>
            </button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button data-value="3" class="key">3
                <span>d e f</span>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button data-value="4" class="key">4
                <span>g h i</span>
            </button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button data-value="5" class="key">5
                <span>j k l</span>
            </button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button data-value="6" class="key">6
                <span>m n o</span>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button data-value="7" class="key">7
            <span>p q r s</span>
            </button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button data-value="8" class="key">8
                <span>t u v</span>
            </button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button data-value="9" class="key">9
                <span>w x y z</span>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button data-value="*" class="key">*</button></td>
        <td><button data-value="0" class="key">0</button></td>
        <td><button data-value="#" class="key">#</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Please run code snippet

Now,
Click 2 -> output should be -> a
Click 2 again -> output should be -> b
Click 2 again -> output should be -> c

Click 3 -> output should be -> c(+d) => cd
click 3 again -> output should be -> c(+e) => ce
click 3 after 2-3 second -> output should be -> ce(+d) => ced

longpress 1 -> output should be -> ced(+1) => ced1
longpress 2 -> output should be -> ced1(+2) => ced12
longpress 3 -> output should be -> ced12(+3) => ced123

finally when you..
click 1 -> output should be -> ced123(+".") => ced123.
click 1 again -> output should be -> ced123(+",") => ced123,
click 1 again -> output should be -> ced123(+"!") => ced123!

I could not find any solution for this kind of time related program. If you have enough time to help me solve it then I would be very grateful. If you have any guideline or any documentation related to this please provide me..

Comment: Was the JS snippet given, and that has to be used?

Comment: yes it was given during that time & javascrip used  jQuery 2.1.1 you can go there from here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E2Lmb/)

Comment: One more thing has to be follow that you can only do your code in function t9

Comment: Detecting a "longpress" is quite difficult, if you have to start it with a mouseup. Are you sure the used event was mouseup instead of mousedown?

Comment: I think, you should give the problem another try, the key is to make a button identify whether if it was a long press, or not

Comment: but you can only code inside function t9 in javascript then how can i check that click is longpress or not?

Comment: that would be difficult, in fact I cant think of a solution without using mouse down and mouse up events

Comment: I think it's same like non-smartphone mobile phone numeric pad we use for messging

Comment: it's can be solve if you use setTimeout after every click and add an attribute in html like on click add attribute "replace='yes'" then after 1-2 second fire setTimeout and change it to "replace='no'" but it's create too many issue

Comment: jQuery events have a timestamp, but I'm not sure, if a mouseup event can access a timestamp of a mousedown event, especially, if it wasn't listened.

Comment: but #Teemu you have only two things 1) textbox current value & 2) which button you pressed

Comment: Nope, you've much more, the `event` object contains a lot of information of the event, and then there's also the internal object for the events in jQuery event model, which usually is not meant to be accessed.

Comment: not sure, if it would be cheating, but you always get the button using document.getElement... then attach events to it

Comment: this programme cracked my self-confidence when i was failed at that time, because i was thinking that i can do any programme in javascript but i was wrong. so....till now i am mad of this

Comment: @Teemu, no other information is being passed to the function

Comment: @roddmarsh I dont understand how you would use setTimeOut for the long press

Comment: Does the interviewer know the answer ?

Comment: @Flying Gambit it's only for replace last character not for longpress. to replace last character, onClick add an attribute to pressed button like "replace='yes'" and it will be "replace='no'" after 2 second of setTimeout so you can check that you need to replace last char or concat it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to remember last time and last button and compare them to know whether you should "increment" a character or not.

The actual increment will be easier if you also remember the last index, but you can also get it from the last character of previous text if you want to.

As for the long press, it may be the real test because the code provided does not give you enough to detect that.  Ultimately you need a mousedown to determine whether a long press has happened.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#phone").find("button").mouseup(function(event){
        var button_pressed = $(event.currentTarget).data("value");
        $("#result").val(t9($("#result").val(),button_pressed));
    }).mousedown( t9_down );
});

function t9(text,button_pressed){
    const { last_time, last_down, last_button } = t9, // Load states
        keys = [ '0', '.,!', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqrs', 'tuv', 'wxyz' ],
        long_press = 1000, // ms
        timeout = 2000; // ms
    let index = 0, // Which character?
        now = new Date().getTime(),
        candidates = keys[ button_pressed ] || button_pressed; // All characters
    // Handle complex buttons
    if ( candidates.length > 1 ) {
       if ( last_button === button_pressed && now - last_time <= timeout ) {
           // Quick click of same button
           const len = text.length - 1,
               last_char = text.charAt( len );
           index = ( candidates.indexOf( last_char ) + 1 ) % candidates.length;
           text = text.substr( 0, len );
       } else if ( now - last_down > long_press )
           // Long press
           now = candidates = button_pressed;
       // Save states
       Object.assign( t9, { last_time: now, last_down: 0, last_button: button_pressed } );
    }
    text += String( candidates )[ index ];
    return text;
}

function t9_down(event) {
    if ( ! ~~$(event.currentTarget).data("value") ) return;
    t9.last_down = new Date().getTime();
}
```

```css
#phone button{
    height: 50px;
    width: 75px;
}
#phone button span{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
#result{
    width: 225px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="phone">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <input type="text" id="result" />
  <tr>
    <td><button data-value="1" class="key">1<span>. , !</span></button>
    <td><button data-value="2" class="key">2<span>a b c</span></button>
    <td><button data-value="3" class="key">3<span>d e f</span></button>
  <tr>
    <td><button data-value="4" class="key">4<span>g h i</span></button>
    <td><button data-value="5" class="key">5<span>j k l</span></button>
    <td><button data-value="6" class="key">6<span>m n o</span></button>
  <tr>
    <td><button data-value="7" class="key">7<span>p q r s</span></button>
    <td><button data-value="8" class="key">8<span>t u v</span></button>
    <td><button data-value="9" class="key">9<span>w x y z</span></button>
  <tr>
    <td><button data-value="*" class="key">*</button>
    <td><button data-value="0" class="key">0</button>
    <td><button data-value="#" class="key">#</button>
</table>
```

Comment: @roddmarsh That may be the real test - to see whether and when you realise that you don't have enough info to handle long press.  I'll see if I can find a workaround later, but I have a baby to take care for now.

Comment: any time dear...thanks & i have been waiting for your answer. you are seriously genius........

Comment: @roddmarsh Updated answer to include long press handling.  Also added comment to the code.

Comment: is it possible without t9_down function?

Comment: @roddmarsh Yes.  You can combine t9 and t9_down into one function: if button_pressed is undefined then you run the down code. But I don't think that is a better answer, since you still need to call mousedown, and I'll definitely score down someone who'd rather combine the two functions. :p  An alternative is to add mousedown listener in t9, but that means the first press would not be registered as long click.